# How do you generate all permutations of n variables, each one taking on 1 or 0?

Tags: haskell

For example, let's say I want to generate all permutations of two values,each one could be 0 or 1, I would get:

```
[11,10,01,00]
```

Note here the first variable varies the slowest, so it stays fixed while the remaining one varies.

In the case of three variables, I would get

```
[111,110,101,100,011,010,001,000]
```

I see that there should be a recursive definition for it, but it's not clear enough in my head so that I could express it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not about permutations, but about combinations and you can generate them easily in Haskell:

```
replicateM 3 "01"
= ["000","001","010","011","100","101","110","111"]
```

If you need actual integers:

```
replicateM 3 [0, 1]
= [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],
   [1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Finally if the values at the various positions are different:

```
sequence [".x", ".X", "-+"]
= ["..-","..+",".X-",".X+","x.-","x.+","xX-","xX+"]
```

This too works for integers, of course:

```
sequence [[0,1], [0,2], [0,4]]
= [[0,0,0],[0,0,4],[0,2,0],[0,2,4],
   [1,0,0],[1,0,4],[1,2,0],[1,2,4]]
```

Comment: It just took me 3 minutes to figure out why `replicateM` manages to do this. Haskell is fantastic for breaking people's minds! :-D

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I think the devil is not as much in `replicateM` as it is in the list monad (and `String` being a type synonym) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want permuations, as in a list of lists, here's a solution using a list monad.

```
\n -> mapM (const [0, 1]) [1..n]
```

Comment: http://images.wikia.com/victorious/images/2/23/Oh-boy.gif I have no idea how it works but it's beautiful

Comment: Use `replicateM` or `sequence` instead.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited based on feedback)

The smallest n-digit binary integer is 000..0 (n times), which is 0.

The largest n-digit binary integer is 111...1 (n times), which is 2^n - 1.

Generate the integers from `0` to `1<<n - 1` and print out the values you have.

Haskell's Int should be safe for <= 28 binary variables.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This question is tagged "haskell," so "no recursion needed" is blatantly wrong.

Comment: That is a valid point, Kristopher. However, I personally think that using recursion here won't make for a simpler, more elegant method.

Comment: It won't make for a simple elegant method, it will make for the *only* method.  There's no such thing as "iterating" in haskell, recursion *is* the only way.  (Even Koterpillar's solution, which is correct, uses recursion.)

Comment: I stand corrected. As a non-Haskell user, I should have paid closer attention to the tag before proposing the solution.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: There's no need for explicit recursion, though. Saying recursion is needed feels to me a little like saying "really though, it's imperative, because it's compiled down to bytecode"

Answer (score 1):

```
ghci> :m +Data.List
ghci> permutations [0,1]
[[0,1],[1,0]]
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know haskel, but here is a block of psuedo code on how I do permutations.

```
var positions = [0,0,0];
var max = 1;

done:
while(true){
    positions[0]++; //Increment by one
    for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if(positions[i] > max){ //If the current position is at max carry over
            positions[i] = 0;
            if(i+1 >= positions.length){ //no more positions left
                break done; 
            }
            positions[i+1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is far from how Haskell works and even farther from how you would do it in Haskell.